# Why do I get error message "Error: GraphQL error: claims key: 'https://hasura.io/jwt/claims' not found"?

Tags: authentication, graphql, jwt, auth0, hasura

I'm using Auth0 for authentication and authorization in my app and I've specified a rule for jwt-tokens. But I get this error message in the console, "Error: GraphQL error: claims key: 'https://hasura.io/jwt/claims' not found". 
Why? What could I possibly have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your JWT token is not formatted correctly. Your JWT token must be formatted according to Hasura's spec described here:

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authentication/jwt.html#the-spec

Here is an example:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true,
  "iat": 1516239022,
  "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["editor","user", "mod"],
    "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
    "x-hasura-user-id": "1234567890",
    "x-hasura-org-id": "123",
    "x-hasura-custom": "custom-value"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error and my JWT token is formatted correctly:

{
  'https://hasura.io/jwt/claims': {
    'x-hasura-default-role': 'user',
    'x-hasura-allowed-roles': ['user'],
    'x-hasura-user-id': uid,
  },
}